# Filling an empty matrix with values from tibble in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have generated a tibble which is formatted like this:

```
  V1 n
1 "Sam,Chris" 30
2 "Sam,Peter" 81
3 "Jeff,James" 5
4 "David,Jones" 6
5 "Harry,Otto" 8
```

I also have a large matrix where every row and column is titled after a name, and each name appears once. So I need to split each row of V1, So that the index of the matrix that is:

```
   [Sam]
[Chris]30
```

For example, so I'd need to somehow split by the comma and then fill the matrix, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%      
  separate_rows(V1, sep=",")
```

---

If we want to get the output as a `matrix`

```
df1 %>%
   separate(V1, into = c("V1", "V2"), sep=",") %>%
   spread(V2, n, fill = 0) %>%
   column_to_rownames("V1")
#    Chris James Jones Otto Peter
#David    0    0    6   0    0
#Harry    0    0    0    8    0
#Jeff     0     5   0   0  0
#@Sam      30    0    0   0   81
```

It can be converted to a square matrix, by including the first and last names both in row and column names

```
tmp <- df1 %>%
       separate(V1, into = c("V1", "V2"), sep=",") 
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(tmp[1:2])))
tmp %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(V1, V2), factor, levels = lvls) %>%
  spread(V2, n, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("Sam,Chris", "Sam,Peter", "Jeff,James", 
"David,Jones", "Harry,Otto"), n = c(30L, 81L, 5L, 6L, 8L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Yeah sorry n another column which has the value. I tried this with my set and the output for the first n is NA, can I ask why I should do this? I don't really understand sorry

Comment: @RahimDina. In your expected you showed `Sam` and emtpy value

Comment: Oh I think I understand the confusion now, those aren't separate rows.

Comment: @RahimDina. Okay, in that case, you just need `separate_rows`..  Please find the updated code

Comment: But how do I fill the matrix with the values?

Comment: @RahimDina. Where is the matrix in the post?  Can you update your post

Comment: The second part was me trying to draw a matrix, the desired output would be that in the [Sam, Chris] position of the matrix, the value is 30. In the [Jeff, James] it is 5 for example.

Comment: @RahimDina. I updated the post.  Not clear about the matrix.  Is it an already existing matrix or wanted to create new.  In that case the second option should work

Comment: Thanks, would this keep each column,row unique. So that even if Sam appeared multiple times in the data, there'd only be 1 Sam row and 1 Sam column for example?

Comment: @RahimDina. As long as both the first and last names are not  duplicates, it would keep it as such.  But, if there are multiple persons with the same, we may need a grouping column i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(grp = row_number())` and then do the `separate`

Comment: Sorry my actual data has like hundreds of thousands of rows, so it takes a while to work it. When I opened the outputted matrix in RStudio it crashed, so I'm having to reload everything

Comment: @RahimDina. You can. test. on a small subset of rows.  If this is slow, a faster option is `data.table` `dcast(setDT(df1)[, c("V1", "V2") := tstrsplit(V1, ",")], V1~ V2, value.var = 'n')`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to have worked. Is there a way to replace all of the NAs with 0?

Comment: @RahimDina. Just change the `spread` with `spread(V2, n, fill = 0)`

Comment: Thanks, sorry again I realised that the matrix I've generated which I was trying to make a graph with won't work because it isn't square, is there a way to make it square?

Comment: @RahimDIna. It can be made to square, but my question is that the first and last names could be different.  One way is. to create both values as row and column names and then fill with 0.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I created the dataframe, so that they were sorted alphabetically when generating V1 and then grouped by V1, a count was added and then unique(), so there shouldn't a case of Sam Chris and Chris Sam. But yeah the instances where they don't match should be 0. The alternative is creating an edge list and node list but I can't really figure that one out at all

Comment: @RahimDina. I updated with an option.  Please check

Comment: I got this error:  Error in list2(...) : object 'lvls' not found

Comment: @RahimDina. Have you used `tmp <- df1 %>%
       separate(V1, into = c("V1", "V2"), sep=",");
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(tmp[1:2])))`

Comment: Sorry I must've missed it, thank you for all the help